# Create a boot loader for classes that are depending on each other

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have the following JSON :

```json
[{
  "id": "main",
  "deps": [],
  "class": "export class MainClass { constructor() { console.log('I am the main class'); } }"
}, {
  "id": "logger",
  "deps": ["main"],
  "class": "export class MainClass { constructor(main) { console.log('I am the logger : ', main); } }"
}, {
  "id": "feat",
  "deps": ["main", "logger"],
  "class": "export class MainClass { constructor(main, logger) { console.log('I am a feature: ', main, logger); } }"
}]
```

As you can see, the JSON contains

- A class ID to identify it in a unique manner
- A list of dependencies for the class, that are injected into the constructor
- Some code for the class itself

Suppose I can already create the classes, and inject their dependencies in the correct order.

My issue is :

**How can I build the classes in the correct order so that each dependency is loaded correctly ?

(In other words, how to sort this array in the correct order)**

My initial approach was to give a "level" to each class, depending on their number of dependencies. But that does not guarantee the order, hence the dependencies are not defined ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

PS : I'm using Angular, hence the tags, I don't know what else to put, so if I mistagged the question, feel free to edit it

**EDIT** Here is a MCVE to help you test it out :

```js
const classes = [{
    id: "main",
    deps: [],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor() { console.log('I am the main class'); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "logger",
    deps: ["main"],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor(main) { console.log('I am the logger : ', main); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "feat",
    deps: ["main", "logger"],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor(main, logger) { console.log('I am a feature: ', main, logger); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "levelIssue",
    deps: ["feat"],
    class: "class levelIssueClass { constructor(feat) { console.log('I depend on feature : ', feat); } }",
  },
];

// This is the variable that should have everything sorted
const ordered = classes.sort((a, b) => a.deps.length - b.deps.length);

const instanciated = {};

for (const c of ordered) {
  eval('window.module = ' + c.class);
  const deps = c.deps.map(id => instanciated[id]);
  const tmp = new window.module(...deps);
  instanciated[c.id] = tmp;
  delete window.module;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your example you kind of already have a "level" for each class if you considerer the `deps.length` property.

So if you load at first all of your classes with no dependecies (`deps: []`), then after the ones with only one dependecy and so on you just need to sort the array that way.

[EDIT] Before you do that you should map your `deps` to get the entire list, so the class will be at the right level before you do the loading.

It would look something like this:

```
const data = [{
    id: "main",
    deps: [],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor() { console.log('I am the main class'); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "logger",
    deps: ["main"],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor(main) { console.log('I am the logger : ', main); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "feat",
    deps: ["main", "logger"],
    class: "class MainClass { constructor(main, logger) { console.log('I am a feature: ', main, logger); } }",
  },
  {
    id: "levelIssue",
    deps: ["feat"],
    class: "class levelIssueClass { constructor(feat) { console.log('I depend on feature : ', feat); } }",
  },
];

// map dependencies
const classes = data.map((item) => {
  // gets the dependencies from dependencies and concats into one array
  const deps = item.deps.concat(item.deps.map(classId => data.find(c => c.id === classId).deps)).flat();
  return {
     ...item,
     deps,
  }; 
});

// sort by deps.length
classes.sort((a, b) => (a.deps.length > b.deps.length) ? 1 : -1).forEach((item) => {
  // load item
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your proposal, unfortunately it does not work as intended. I have edited the original post to add a new class, with a single dependency, which depends on a class with two : the dependency gets undefined. I also added a MCVE if you wish to test it out !

Comment: I've edited my answer with a map proposal, check if it fits your needs now :)